# Loading undefined stored variables without quotes?

Tags: batch-file

This code reads every (previously unknown) file in `%appdata%\saves` and converts the `filename` into a variable name, and the file content into the variable value. The file `%appdata%\saves\home` would result in `%home%` variable carrying value `"D:\"`...

```
for /f "delims=" %%s in ('dir "%appdata%\saves" /b /s /a-d 2^>nul') do (
    set /p %%~ns=<"%%s"
)
```

The problem is that the variable is wrapped in quotes, which I need permanently out. I can't remove them outside the block because the variables will be unknown. I have to use quotes while saving like `echo "%fullpath%">%appdata%\saves\home` in order to handle special characters like ampersand.

So I either need a solution for not adding the quotes in the first place, or removing the quotes while loading, or a method for storing the variables in a single known file, where all quotes can be easily removed, which ever is the minimalist way.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the sample contents of a file, what it does that you don't want it to do, and what you actually want it to do.  I am having trouble understanding where precisely you are having problems with double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will offer up two slightly different variations to your code.

If you know there will only be one line in the file then just use another `FOR` command to read the file. Then you can use the tilde to remove the quotes.

```
for /f "delims=" %%s in ('dir "%appdata%\saves" /b /s /a-d 2^>nul') do (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("%%s") DO set "%%~ns=%%~G"
)
```

If you really want to use file redirection then just use delayed expansion with another `FOR` command to strip the quotes.

```
for /f "delims=" %%s in ('dir "%appdata%\saves" /b /s /a-d 2^>nul') do (
    set /p %%~ns=<"%%s"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ("!%%~ns!") do endlocal &set "%%~ns=%%~G"
)
```

The quotes I am using with the `SET` commands help protect with special characters. They do not get assigned to the variable.

Comment: that first one works beautifully in just 2 lines, it's my favorite. I am trying to add another variable into the save file like `"D:\"|"Target directory: [D:\]"` but I can't load it using this change: `...delims=|" %%g in ("%%s") do set "%%~ns=%%~g" && set "%%~ns_display=%%~h"`

Comment: @Bricktop, you need to use the `TOKENS` option. `tokens=1,2 delims=|`.  But seeing what you are trying to do, you are really making this harder than it has to be.  I am not sure why you wouldn't set this up like a standard `INI` file where each line has the variable name and value assigned to it. Then it literally becomes one line of code to set all of your variables.

Comment: very interesting, researching now. please elaborate.

Comment: I see how reading the file would be easier (in a single line of code), but how would I update a value within the file?

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe I will try and see if this helps:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%s in ('dir "%appdata%\saves" /b /s /a-d 2^>nul') do (
    set /p %%~ns=<"%%s"
    set %%~ns=!%%~ns:"=!
)
```

You could also use a prefix on your variable and then access all of them with the `set` command:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%s in ('dir "%appdata%\saves" /b /s /a-d 2^>nul') do (
    set /p _tmpvar_%%~ns=<"%%s"
)
for /f "delims== tokens=1*" %%a in ('set _tmpvar_') do set "%%a=%%~b"
set _tmpvar_
```